# Tagging more than one user in a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, users

I don't see why we shouldn't be able to tag more than one user in a comment - I understand that a comment should only be a reply to either the OP of the question or answer, or a direct comment reply, but it would be useful to be able to tag more than one user in a comment.

The most obvious concern with this feature is tagging spam - to prevent this, limiting the users you can tag to the number of users in the comment thread would be necessary.

This feature would eliminate the need for multiple comments, to CC a user on a comment which already has another user tagged in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  [The comment system allows only one @user to be notified by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/160519).  So far, nobody has been willing to change it.